# How to get the hours difference beetwen today and 08 AM next day - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I'v an application where I send SMS 3x/day with 5 hours difference, but, if the current time is bigger then 17:00, the next send is on next day at 08:00.

I'm tryng like this, but null is given:

```
if(current_time() < '17:00', DATE_ADD(current_time(), INTERVAL 5 HOUR), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIME(), INTERVAL (TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIME(),'08:00')) HOUR));
```

Someone can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
case when current_time < '17:00:00'
    then now() + interval 5 hour
    else current_date + interval 1 day + interval 8 hour
end
```

Note that this returns a value of `datetime` datatype rather than `time`, because you seem to want a date portion.

If you do want a `time` only then it is even simpler:

```
case when current_time < '17:00:00'
    then current_time + interval 5 hour
    else '08:00:00'
end
```

Comment: Nice! I thought if I add 1 day, the "current time" would be same hour but in the next day. I made like this and got what I wanted.


select if(current_time() < '17:00:00', DATE_ADD(current_time(), INTERVAL 5 HOUR), DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 8 HOUR));